# Is this matrix consistent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I think the answer in the back of the book is wrong. I have the following matrix

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
  \blacksquare&*&*&*&*&*\\
  0&\blacksquare&*&*&0&*\\
  0&0&0&0&\blacksquare&0\\
  0&0&0&0&*&\blacksquare
\end{array}
\right] $$

The black boxes are nonzero numbers, and the asterisks can be anything. The back of the book says there may be a solution, and if so, there will be infinite solutions.

If I make the bottom right black box equal to 1, then I don't see how we can get a solution.

Comment: From the equation before the last one you get that the last variable must be zero. Eliminating that variable from the last equation, you get $0=\blacksquare$, which is incompatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are right, indeed from the third equation the $5^{th}$ unknown must be equal to zero and thus the black box in the last row should be equal to zero.

Comment: The bottom right $*$ only has to be different from zero, not equal to the box to its right. Remember that those are the coefficients.

Comment: @glofatics Yes you are right! I've revised my answer. Thanks